# Form array only showing one item

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms with a form builder to populate my form.

I defined my form like this:

```
public myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  something: [''],
  people: this.formBuilder.array([this.newPerson()]),
});
```

The `newPerson()` function looks like this:

```
public newPerson(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: [''],
    lastName: [''],
  },);
}
```

In OnInit() I want to populate this form with some data and here is where I have issues. If I do:

```
this.getPeople().patchValue([
  { firstName: 'Bla', lastName: 'Bla' },
  { firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Test' }, 
]);
```

I only see the Bla Bla in my form but not Test Test. Why is that so?

Comment: `this.formBuilder.array([this.newPerson()])` => this creates a formArray with single formGroup. You'd have to call `this.newPerson()` twice to create 2 formgroups, and then patchValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.formBuilder.array([this.newPerson()])` => this creates a formArray with single formGroup. You'd have to call this.newPerson() twice to create 2 formgroups, and then patchValue

```
public myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  something: [''],
  people: this.formBuilder.array([this.newPerson(), this.newPerson()]),
});
```